# Page gets slow when I show new elements on a Swipable slider, ¿How can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I making a swipable slider using touch events, when remains one visible element of visible elements I want to load new elements, for that I'm using this method:

```
  initInteractionWithItems(elementsToMakeVisible) {
    let totalMargin = 0 //the items are stacked and in the loop, the margin gradually gets bigger
    let indexZ = 0  //the indexZ also gets bigger in the loop (is the z-index for the stacked elems)
    const sizeItems = this.items.length  
    let styleElement = document.createElement("style") 
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement)

    if (elementsToMakeVisible) {
      firstInTheList.style.zIndex = "" + (elementsToMakeVisible + 1) * 1000
    } else {
      elementsToMakeVisible = this.itemsVisibleLength
    }

    totalMargin = this.marginTopFactor * elementsToMakeVisible
    indexZ = elementsToMakeVisible * 1000

    //while the list have elements, I show a portion of those 
    while ((elementsToMakeVisible !== 0) && (this.elementsCount < sizeItems)) {
      let rule = ".swipeItem-" + this.elementsCount + "{ opacity: " +  "1;" + "margin-top:" + totalMargin + "px;" + "z-index:" + indexZ + ";}"
      this.items[this.elementsCount].classList.add("swipeItem-" + this.elementsCount)  
      totalMargin -= this.marginTopFactor
      indexZ -= 1000
      elementsToMakeVisible--
      this.elementsCount++
      styleElement.sheet.insertRule(rule)
    }


  }
}
```

The method do the job of show the elements, this same method I use when the page loads and I need
to show the first elements. but when I have to show more elements when the slider have only one element
the page gets slow, the element I removed (because I swipe it) gets stuck and lates to hide totally. finally the elements that I want load are show.

When I have to delete an element because was selected I use this method:

```
function sendTarget(event) {

  if (event.cancelable) {
    canSlide = false
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!has_option_selected) {  //if a element has been selected
      event.target.offsetParent.style.transform = "rotateZ(0deg)"
    } else {

      firstInTheList.remove()
      firstInTheList = iteratorItems.next().value
      countElements--

      if (countElements === 1) { //if in the slider remains only one element
        swipeReference.initInteractionWithItems(2)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Only the first element have the touch events, and every time an element gets selected I removed that element and the first element will be the next in the array I use for have the elements I want to show, for that I use this generator function:

```
function* getFirstItem(arrayElements) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {
    arrayElements[i].addEventListener("touchstart", getCoords, true)
    arrayElements[i].addEventListener("touchmove", slideTarget, true)
    arrayElements[i].addEventListener("touchend", sendTarget, true)

    yield arrayElements[i]
  }
}
```

When I remove an element and I don't have to show new elements the sendTarget method works fine. the trouble is when I have to show new elements and I have to inkove initInteractionWithItems again.

How can I fix that?, what approach can I do for solve this performance trouble?

The full project:

```js
let has_option_selected = false
let canSlide = false
let firstTime = true
let current_coord_x
let current_coord_y
let firstInTheList = null
let swipeItsClassName
let countElements = 3
let swipeReference = null
let iteratorItems = null


function getCoords(event) {
  if (event.target.offsetParent.classList.contains("swipeItem") && event.cancelable) {
    event.preventDefault()
    canSlide = true
    current_coord_x = event.changedTouches[0].clientX
    current_coord_y = event.changedTouches[0].clientY
  } else {
    current_coord_x = event.clientX
    current_coord_y = event.clientY
  }
}


function calcRotation(translateXValue, element) {

  let rotateValue = translateXValue * 0.10

  if (rotateValue <= -15) {
    notifySelection(element, 1)
    return -15
  } else if (rotateValue >= 15) {
    notifySelection(element, -1)
    return 15
  } else {
    notifySelection(element, 0)
    return rotateValue
  }
}
function moveTarget(event, target) {
  let translateX = (event.changedTouches[0].clientX - current_coord_x)
  let translateY = (event.changedTouches[0].clientY - current_coord_y)

  if (event instanceof TouchEvent) {

    if (firstTime) {
      translateY += 100
    }
    target.style.transform = "translateX(" + translateX + "px" + ")" + " " + "translateY(" + translateY + "px)" + " " + "rotateZ(" + calcRotation(translateX, target) + "deg)"
  }

}


function notifySelection(target, state) {
  if (state === 1) {
    //target.offsetParent.style.color = "green"
    has_option_selected = true
  } else if (state === -1) {
    //target.offsetParent.style.color = "red"
    has_option_selected = true
  } else {
    // target.offsetParent.style.color = "yellow"
    has_option_selected = false
  }
}

function sendTarget(event) {

  if (event.cancelable) {
    canSlide = false
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!has_option_selected) {
      event.target.offsetParent.style.transform = "rotateZ(0deg)"
    } else {

     
      firstInTheList.remove()
      firstInTheList = iteratorItems.next().value
      countElements--
   
      if (countElements === 1) {
        swipeReference.initInteractionWithItems(2)
      }

    }
  }
}

function slideTarget(e) {
  let parentTarget = e.target.offsetParent
  let hasClassItem = parentTarget.classList.contains("swipeItem")
  if ((canSlide && e.cancelable && hasClassItem) && (firstInTheList === parentTarget)) {
    e.preventDefault()
    moveTarget(e, parentTarget)
  }
}


function* getFirstItem(arrayElements) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {
    arrayElements[i].addEventListener("touchstart", getCoords, true)
    arrayElements[i].addEventListener("touchmove", slideTarget, true)
    arrayElements[i].addEventListener("touchend", sendTarget, true)

    yield arrayElements[i]
  }
}

class SwipeSlider {

  constructor(swipeItems, marginTopFactor = 30, itemsVisibleLenght = 3) {
    //swipeItsClassName = swipeItemsClassName
    swipeReference = this
    this.items = swipeItems
    iteratorItems = getFirstItem(this.items)
    firstInTheList = iteratorItems.next().value
    this.itemsVisibleLength = itemsVisibleLenght
    this.marginTopFactor = marginTopFactor
    this.totalMarginSize = (this.marginTopFactor * itemsVisibleLenght)
    this.elementsCount = 0
  }

  initInteractionWithItems(elementsToMakeVisible) {
    let totalMargin = 0
    let indexZ = 0
    const sizeItems = this.items.length
    let styleElement = document.createElement("style")
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement)
    
    if (elementsToMakeVisible) {
      firstInTheList.style.zIndex = "" + (elementsToMakeVisible + 1) * 1000
    } else {
      elementsToMakeVisible = this.itemsVisibleLength
    }

    totalMargin = this.marginTopFactor * elementsToMakeVisible
    indexZ = elementsToMakeVisible * 1000

    while ((elementsToMakeVisible !== 0) && (this.elementsCount < sizeItems)) {
      let rule = ".swipeItem-" + this.elementsCount + "{ opacity: " +  "1;" + "margin-top:" + totalMargin + "px;" + "z-index:" + indexZ + ";}"
      this.items[this.elementsCount].classList.add("swipeItem-" + this.elementsCount)  
      totalMargin -= this.marginTopFactor
      indexZ -= 1000
      elementsToMakeVisible--
      this.elementsCount++
      styleElement.sheet.insertRule(rule)
    }
    
    
  }
}

function getArrayElements(elements) {
  let array = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    array.push(elements[i])
  }
  return array
}

let arrayElements = getArrayElements(document.querySelectorAll(".swipeItem"))
let slider = new SwipeSlider(arrayElements)
slider.initInteractionWithItems()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Solway&display=swap');
:root{
  --fontHeadingProspect: 25px;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.swipeImg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 15px;

}

.swipeContainer{
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(300px,auto);
 
  
}

.gridSwipeItem{
  display: grid;
}

.swipeItem{
  background-color: rgb(252, 237, 223);
  position: relative;
  max-width: 270px; 
  grid-column: 1 ;
  grid-row: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Solway', serif;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(233, 209, 130);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  z-index: 0;
}

.headingProspect{
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  font-size: var(--fontHeadingProspect);
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  align-self: end;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.headingProspectSection{
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  justify-self: start;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: 'Solway', serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f74040;
}



.selection-zone{
  background-image: rgb(255, 225, 169);
}

.visibleTarget{

  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="selection-zone">
    <div class="swipeContainer" id="swipeContainer">
      <article class="swipeItem gridSwipeItem" id="swipeItem">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200" class="swipeImg">
        <h1 id="prospectState" class="headingProspect">Rose Ann, 19</h1>
      </article>
      <article class="swipeItem gridSwipeItem">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200" class="swipeImg">
        <h1 id="prospectState" class="headingProspect">Mary Wolfstoncraft, 24</h1>
      </article>
      <article class="swipeItem gridSwipeItem">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200" class="swipeImg">
        <h1 id="prospectState" class="headingProspect">Rose Doe, 34</h1>
      </article>
     <article class="swipeItem gridSwipeItem">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200" class="swipeImg">
        <h1 id="prospectState" class="headingProspect">Joane Smith, 34</h1>
      </article>
      <article class="swipeItem gridSwipeItem">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200" class="swipeImg">
        <h1 id="prospectState" class="headingProspect">Mary Wolfstoncraft, 24</h1>
      </article> 
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Too much code can you simplify to shorter

Comment: or make a working example on codesandbox or jsfiddle